# How to show the user only tasks he has marked as "done"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two models:

```
User(id:integer name:string) and Task(id:integer task:string).
```

The Scenario is:

1. I add some records in model Task. These tasks are visible to everyone.
2. The user clicks "Done".
3. The Task is marked for the user as "done".

How to show the user only the tasks he has done?

Comment: I am sorry to have missed an important point. The task is still available to other users who have not already done.

Answer (score 1):

I would something like:

Create a method in the task model called done

```
def done
   where(:status => 'done', :user = current_user)
end
```

Then in the tasks controller do @done = Task.done

Then in the view

```
<%= @done.each do |one_done| %>
  <%= one_done.name %> 
<% end %>
```

You will need to be sure that `User has_many :tasks` and `Task belongs_to :user` **and that migrations have created the foreign key field in `Task (user_id)`**.